# Python 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file' while getting input inside a loop (I'm not opening any files)

Tags: python

before we start, this issue only occurs on a linux device, when I try it on Windows, it works totally fine, here's some specs

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python Version: Python 3.9.2
```

Anyways, the problem is when I try to get an input the second time inside a loop, it gives me a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file' even though I do not use any files. Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/main.py", line 17, in main
    menu.print_main_menu()
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/menu.py", line 76, in print_main_menu
    game = Game() 
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/Game.py", line 63, in __init__
    game_actions[action]()
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/Game.py", line 42, in _play_local_action
    response = create_or_join_actions[create_or_join]()
  File "/home/joshgil/Codes/Connect4/Game.py", line 98, in _create_game
    answer = inquirer.text(
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/InquirerPy/prompts/input.py", line 201, in execute
    result = self._session.prompt(default=self._default)
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/prompt.py", line 1020, in prompt
    return self.app.run(
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 887, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 816, in run_async
    return await _run_async2()
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 792, in _run_async2
    result = await _run_async()
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 721, in _run_async
    with self.input.raw_mode(), self.input.attach(
  File "/home/joshgil/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/input/vt100.py", line 129, in raw_mode
    return raw_mode(self.stdin.fileno())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Here's the code that creates this error

```py
        while (True):
            if (len(self._user_requesting) == 0):
                continue

            for index, user in self._user_requesting.items():

                user = UserSettingsSchema().load(user)
                accept = ''

                # Errors out here on the second while(True) loop iteration
                answer = inquirer.text(
                    message= f'The user "{user.username}" is requesting to join, accept request?',
                    validate= lambda text: text.lower() in ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'],
                    invalid_message= 'Please answer with a yes or no (y/n)'
                ).execute()

                if (accept.lower() in ['yes', 'y']):
                    self._user_requesting = []
                    self._opponent = user

                    sock.send_str('accepted', user.private_topic)
                    break

                else:
                    sock.send_str('declined', user.private_topic)

                    self._user_requesting[user.private_topic] = None

                    print(f'The user "{user.username}" is declined ...')
                    print('Waiting for a user to connect ...')

                    continue
            else:
                self._user_requesting = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] != None, self._user_requesting.items()))
```

If you want to see the whole code:
https://github.com/JoshuaPelealu/Connect4/blob/master/Game.py

---

I am using InquirerPy, but that doesn't have anything with the error, because when I used native `input()` function, it still gives me the same error.

I honestly do not know what is happening, because I do not use any files to run this, and my code does not involve any opening or closing files.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't you have any exit() calls between iterations (in other files)? It seems like exit() or something like that closed sys.stdin between iterations.

Comment: I've found the problem, and it's the fact that the prompt_toolkit module is closing my `sys.stdin()` between iterations. I'm implementing a fix right now, where I'm just going to have a thread handling a request one by one.